# Finding correlated values from second table without resorting to PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables in my database:

a) A table containing values acquired at a certain date (you may think of these as, say, temperature readings):

```
 sensor_id |       acquired      | value
 ----------+---------------------+--------
 1         | 2009-04-01 10:00:00 | 20
 1         | 2009-04-01 10:01:00 | 21
 1         | 2009-04 01 10:02:00 | 20
 1         | 2009-04 01 10:09:00 | 20
 1         | 2009-04 01 10:11:00 | 25
 1         | 2009-04 01 10:15:00 | 30
 ...
```

The interval between the readings may differ, but the combination of (`sensor_id`, `acquired`) is unique.

b) A second table containing time periods and a description (you may think of these as, say, periods when someone turned on the radiator):

```
 sensor_id |      start_date     |       end_date      | description
 ----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------
 1         | 2009-04-01 10:00:00 | 2009-04-01 10:02:00 | some description
 1         | 2009-04-01 10:10:00 | 2009-04-01 10:14:00 | something else
```

Again, the length of the period may differ, but there will never be overlapping time periods for any given sensor.

I want to get a result that looks like this for any sensor and any date range:

```
sensor id |     start date      | v1 |       end date      | v2 | description
----------+---------------------+----+---------------------+----+------------------
1         | 2009-04-01 10:00:00 | 20 | 2009-04-01 10:02:00 | 20 | some description
1         | 2009-04-01 10:10:00 | 25 | 2009-04-01 10:14:00 | 30 | some description
```

Or in text from: given a `sensor_id` and a date range of `range_start` and `range_end`,
find me all time periods which have overlap with the date range (that is, `start_date < range_end` and `end_date > range_start`) and for each of these rows, find the corresponding values from the value table for the time period's `start_date` and `end_date` (find the first row with `acquired > start_date` and `acquired > end_date`).

If it wasn't for the `start_value` and `end_value` columns, this would be a textbook trivial example of how to join two tables.

Can I somehow get the output I need in one SQL statement without resorting to writing a PL/SQL function to find these values?

Unless I have overlooked something blatantly obvious, this can't be done with simple subselects.

Database is Oracle 11g, so any Oracle-specific features are acceptable.

Edit: yes, looping is possible, but I want to know if this can be done with a single SQL select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try. Note the caveats at the end though.

```
SELECT
    RNG.sensor_id,
    RNG.start_date,
    RDG1.value AS v1,
    RNG.end_date,
    RDG2.value AS v2,
    RNG.description
FROM
    Ranges RNG
INNER JOIN Readings RDG1 ON
    RDG1.sensor_id = RNG.sensor_id AND
    RDG1.acquired => RNG.start_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Readings RDG1_NE ON
    RDG1_NE.sensor_id = RDG1.sensor_id AND
    RDG1_NE.acquired >= RNG.start_date AND
    RDG1_NE.acquired < RDG1.acquired
INNER JOIN Readings RDG2 ON
    RDG2.sensor_id = RNG.sensor_id AND
    RDG2.acquired => RNG.end_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Readings RDG1_NE ON
    RDG2_NE.sensor_id = RDG2.sensor_id AND
    RDG2_NE.acquired >= RNG.end_date AND
    RDG2_NE.acquired < RDG2.acquired
WHERE
    RDG1_NE.sensor_id IS NULL AND
    RDG2_NE.sensor_id IS NULL
```

This uses the first reading after the start date of the range and the first reading after the end date (personally, I'd think using the last date before the start and end would make more sense or the closest value, but I don't know your application). If there is no such reading then you won't get anything at all. You can change the INNER JOINs to OUTER and put additional logic in to handle those situations based on your own business rules.

Comment: Neat trick with the OUTER JOIN, now why didn't I think of that? :) Thanks for showing that this can be done, and, indeed, it's me that's dumb.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty straight forward.

1. Find the sensor values for each range. Find a row - I will call acquired of this row just X - where `X > start_date` and not exists any other row with `acquired > start_date` and `acquired < X`. Do the same for end date.
2. Select only the ranges that meet the query - start_date before and end_date after the dates supplied by the query.

In SQL this would be something like that.

```
SELECT R1.*, SV1.aquired, SV2.aquired
FROM ranges R1
INNER JOIN sensor_values SV1 ON SV1.sensor_id = R1.sensor_id
INNER JOIN sensor_values SV2 ON SV2.sensor_id = R1.sensor_id  
WHERE SV1.aquired > R1.start_date
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sensor_values SV3
    WHERE SV3.aquired > R1.start_date
    AND SV3.aquired < SV1.aquired)
AND SV2.aquired > R1.end_date
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sensor_values SV4
    WHERE SV4.aquired > R1.end_date
    AND SV4.aquired < SV2.aquired)
AND R1.start_date < @range_start
AND R1.end_date > @range_end
```

Comment: My mistake, I didn't clarify I was trying to find a way to do this in one SQL query. Otherwise, yes, your idea is quite valid and the most straightforward way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I understood that you want just one query. You can put everything together into one huge query. Not nice, but possible.